# How to remove "/index.php?", ".php", and force trailing slash "/" in URLs? (htaccess rewrite rules)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

we have a **new site** in a new directory in `public_html` as shown in below with yellow.
We need to add rules to `new_site/.htaccess` to fulfill the following three rules:

1. Removing `.php` from the end of URLs
2. Force trailing slash `/` at the end of most urls (excluding .jpg, .png, ...)
3. Removing `/index.php?` from the middle of various URLs.

[image]

Most probably, this would be what I tried to ask:

Currently,

```
domain.com/ns/abc.php
domain.com/ns/abc_abc.php
domain.com/ns/index.php?/abc
domain.com/ns/abc/index.php?/abc
domain.com/ns/abc/abc/index.php?/abc/123
domain.com/ns/abc/abc/index.php?/abc/abc/123/123
```

To

```
domain.com/ns/abc/
domain.com/ns/abc_abc/
domain.com/ns/abc/
domain.com/ns/abc/abc/
domain.com/ns/abc/abc/abc/123/
domain.com/ns/abc/abc/abc/abc/123/123/
```

We have also tried some previously posted rules to do this task. Such as

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ns

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code helped us and removed `index.php`. However, we could not figure it out how to remove `/index.php?`.

Any comment/advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Pretty URL #1 and #3 are same but they are supporting different URLs, that cannot really happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should allow you to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ns/(.*)/(.*)/index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /ns/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ns/(.*)/(.*)/index.php/(.*)/(.*)$ /ns/$1/$2/$3/$4/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ns/(.*)/index.php/(.*)$ /ns/$1/$2/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ns/index.php/(.*)$ /ns/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ns/(.*).php$ /ns/$1/ [R,L]
```

EDIT:
Second try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /ns/(.*)/(.*)/index\.php\?/(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /ns/%2/%3/%4\? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /ns/(.*)/index\.php\?/(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /ns/%2/%3\? [R,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /ns/index\.php\?/(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /ns/%2\? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ns/(.*).php$ /ns/$1/ [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I tried it and it didn't work. Actually, there is also a **?** after index.php and I tried with that too, and didnt work. Thanks again! @Howlin

Comment: You do need `RewriteEngine On` at the start of the htaccess file. s for the `index.php?` I missed that. I'll try and edit if I can add that.

Comment: Yes, I have RewriteEngine On! @Howlin

Comment: Does it at least remove the `.php` from the `abc.php` file? Also what causes there to be a `?` in `index.php`

Comment: Not sure @Howlin ! Its a CMS we are trying to use. If you have time, you can see it here in this [link](http://piwigo.org/demo/index.php?/category/America) It seems to me in the config files they are using **index.php?** Also, still could not remove **.php**

Comment: Great! thanks a lot! I did try the second one! I could not make it work! I somewhat could play around ? mark in the CMS code, and could remove that. However, I am starting to think, maybe the main htaccess file in **public_html** folder would probably create some conflicts. I think this would take some time for me to figure it out! I def appreciate ur help, with both hands on the ground! @Howlin

Comment: No problem, good luck with it! You can mark the question as answered (the tick below the arrows) so other people who had you problem will know how you solved it.